# Php fill array with for loop

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, for-loop, foreach

I'd like to fill an array with data from my database. I created a for loop for that but I think I'm doing something wrong (I'm still very new to programming so sorry for that!)

```
 for($i=0; $i<count($uploadprofile->getAgencies()); $i++){
  foreach($uploadprofile->getAgencies() as $agency) {
    $users[$i] = $agency->getAgencyUser();
    }
  }
  dump(count($users));
```

The dump statement only counts 1 user even though there are supposed to be 3 users in there.

I need this array for then using the data in an other for loop afterwards:

```
   for($i=0; $i<count($users); $i++){
    foreach($users as $user){
      $manager->addNotification($user->toArray()[$i], $notif);
    }
  }
```

I am sure this is really bad coding. It looks like way too many lines for something that simple. So I would be really glad about any advice rather than just a "downvoting"!

If more information about the entities are needed, I'd be happy to provide them!

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, you have too many loops, and I would stick with `foreach`. To build the `$users` array:

```
foreach($uploadprofile->getAgencies() as $agency){
    $users[] = $agency->getAgencyUser();
}
```

To use it:

```
foreach($users as $user){
    $manager->addNotification($user->toArray(), $notif);
}
```

But, if you won't actually need the `$users` array after this then just combine:

```
foreach($uploadprofile->getAgencies() as $agency){
    $user = $agency->getAgencyUser();
    $manager->addNotification($user->toArray(), $notif);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer!
I just tried it your way but when doing dump(count($users)) the number is still 1 but not 3. any ideas why this could be? :)

Comment: Oh and I tried your cut-down-solution as well, the only problem with that is, that the first argument given to the addNotification method can't be an array. That's why I added the exact location ([$i]). But I bet there is a smoother way to solve this, too! Would love to hear it! :D